# How to pass a bitfield (by reference) to a function?

Tags: c, embedded, device-driver, microcontroller, bit-fields

My question is how to pass a bitfield instance by reference to a function.  I have performed this as shown below, but when i eneter the function DAC_set_gain_code, the processor throws an interupt fault.  Is what i am doing correct as far as passing the bitfield goes?

I have created a bitfield (see below) which represents a 24bit register on an DAC chip, which i want to write into and lives in the .h file.

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t rdwr_u8:        1;
    uint8_t not_used_u8:    3;
    uint8_t address_u8:     4;
    uint8_t reserved_u8:    8;
    uint8_t data_u8:        8;
}GAIN_REG_st;
```

I have a function which initialises the bitfield like so:

```
void init(void)
{
    GAIN_REG_st GAIN_x;  //Create instance of bitfield

    //other code here...

    DAC_set_gain_code(channel_u8, gain_code_i8, &GAIN_x);   //Pass address of bitfield

    return;
 }
```

The function which actually populates the bitfield is shown below:

```
void DAC_set_gain_code(uint8_t channel_u8, int8_t gain_code_i8, GAIN_REG_st *GAIN)
{
    /* Populate ZERO_REG_st bitfield */
    GAIN->rdwr_u8       = 0;
    GAIN->not_used_u8 = 0;

    if(channel_u8==0){
        GAIN->address_u8 = GAIN_REGISTER_0;
    }
    else if(channel_u8==1){
        GAIN->address_u8 = GAIN_REGISTER_1;
    }
    else if(channel_u8==2){
        GAIN->address_u8 = GAIN_REGISTER_2;
    }
    else if(channel_u8==3){
        GAIN->address_u8 = GAIN_REGISTER_3;
    }

    GAIN->data_u8 = gain_code_i8;

    return;
}
```

The function prototype for hal_DAC_set_gain_code_uni is:

```
void DAC_set_gain_code(uint8_t channel_u8, int8_t gain_code_i8, GAIN_REG_st *GAIN);
```

Any advise appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what you posted can't possibly compile, or you're not showing what you're actually using (function names mismatch, undeclared variables and/or globals not shown and unused parameters)

Comment: still no go. `ZERO` is not defined in what you posted, and `GAIN` is not used in `DAC_set_gain_code`.

Comment: Sorry about errors in post. That should now be same as actual code.  My MAIN question tho is, am i passing the reference of bitfield correctly?

Comment: My code compiles with no errors, so undeclared variables and function name mismatches are not the issue.

Comment: well, yes, you're passing a pointer correctly (there are no references per se in C). But the code you posted is still not what you have (GAIN has no member named `data_u16`. Are you certain your program is dying in that function and not just a bit after it?

Comment: Where and how do you want to set the GAIN structure to the 24Bit DAC register? I assume, not in the code you posted.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about typos. I've tried to take out the parts relevant so show you guys and keep this pose concise.  The init function is called from main, it takes in all paramaters required, initilises the bitfield from DAC_set_gain_code, then it passes this bitfield to an SPI write function which clocks it out into chips register.

Comment: Mat - Yes ive used break points and found that the fault occurs as soon as DAC_set_gain_code is called from init().

Comment: With the shown code, you are not doing anything with the `GAIN_x` structure, and it won't be available outside the `init` procedure. Is this your intention? With the current code, you could just as well remove the whole `DAC_set_gain_code` call, and this would not have any effect on your software operation.

Comment: It's probably not the function DAC_set_gain_code, instead it could be an (unhandled) interrupt

Comment: Show us the complete example that causes the problem. Could be a problem somewhere else and the debugger just being misled. Do you know which line of code the problem starts to show up?

Answer (score 3):

Since the **real** usage of this code is to write to a hardware register, issues like padding and alignment/ordering of fields **DOES** matter.

I suspect the compiler is using 32-bit ints, and this structure is getting padded to 32-bits, but in the actual code being debugged GAIN_X isn't a local var, you're passing 0xNNNNNNN (or equivalent) - and the address isn't on the "right" boundary (quite possible as it's a 24-bit register).  The compiler will assume you're passing a pointer to a real GAIN_REG_st, not a type-punned address, and so may have made assumptions about alignment.

To access hardware directly from C/C++, you need to **know** how the compiler handles stuff like this, and make sure you lie to the compiler carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be some alignment problem?

Maybe you can play with your compiler's alignment options?
Or try stuffing your structure with a dummy `uint8` at the end?

Comment: But there are no casts, so it can't be an alignment problem

Comment: Yes there can be an alignment problem. When it comes to bit fields, C allows the compiler to go completely haywire and align in completely arbitrary ways. You cannot know how the bit field is aligned, or if there are padding bits/bytes in the middle of it, unless you read the compiler back-end docs in depth. There's also endianess, bit order etc etc: countless unspecified or implementation-defined behavior. The best solution is to not use bit fields at all.

Comment: When i create a bitfield instance `GAIN_REG_st GAIN_x` and i pass `GAIN_x` by reference, is it not the case that i am just passing a pointer to the bitfield? So allignment issuse wouldn't be the issue as i'm not actucally moving the bitfield in memory?

Comment: I disagree with Lundin's comment. The C compiler should be fine with bit fields and passing pointers to them. Lundin's comments might apply if you are trying to cast bit fields to/from other types such as `unsigned char` arrays.

Comment: @Craig Judging by the nature of this bit field, it will be used beyond a "raw boolean buffer". So all the mentioned problems may or may not exist.

Comment: Lundin's comment is not really a problem with alignment, however it's correct that it's not sure to use the gain structure and assume that it have the same bit order like the DAC register